# GeoPandas to_file() saves GeoDataFrame without coordinate system

Tags: python, fiona, geopandas, pandas, anaconda

I have

- GeoPandas 0.2.1 py27_0
- fiona 1.7.0 np110py27_1
- Python 2.7.10

installed in Anaconda 2-4.1.1-Windows-x86 environment. I am able to construct `GeoDataFrame` by reading input datasets and operate the data yet saving an output dataset does not preserve the coordinate system.

```
import geopandas as gpd
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.to_file(driver='ESRI Shapefile',filename=r'C:\GIS\Temp\world_out.shp')
```

The `world_out.shp` does contain the features and the schema of the source shapefile, but coordinate system is undefined (`<Unknown>`). The `world_out.prj` file is 0 KB and doesn't contain anything.

```
out = gpd.read_file(r'C:\GIS\Temp\world_out.shp')
print out.crs
>>> {}
```

I have tested to perform this operation using pure Fiona and it works fine, preserving the `crs` information:

```
import fiona

datasrc_path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\TemplateData\TemplateData.gdb'

with fiona.drivers():
    with fiona.open(datasrc_path,layer='cities') as source:
        meta = source.meta
        meta['driver'] = 'ESRI Shapefile'
        meta['layer'] = source.name

        with fiona.open(r'C:\GIS\CitiesFiona.shp', 'w', **meta) as sink:
            for f in source:
                sink.write(f)
```

The `CitiesFiona.prj` file does contain the information about the coordinate system.

So, it seems as GeoPandas is not able to read/write `crs` of the data frame into the output dataset when calling the `to_file()` method. I have tried calling `to_file()` on `GeoDataFrames` constructed from various sources and datasets and the coordinate system information was never present in the output dataset.

Has anyone run into this issue before? Can anyone test this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have come across this behavior before.

You need to explicitly pass the well known text (crs_wkt) string to  the `to_file()` method. The string will then get passed to `fiona.open()`, which writes out the .prj file.

Using your sample code, doing something like this:

```
ws = r"D:\temp_se"
prj_file = gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres').replace(".shp",".prj")
prj = [l.strip() for l in open(prj_file,'r')][0]
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
temp_shp = os.path.join(ws,"world_out.shp")
world.to_file(filename=temp_shp,driver='ESRI Shapefile',crs_wkt=prj)
```

should produce:
[image]

The `read_file()` and `to_file()` functions simply serve as wrapper functions. They call `fiona.open()`, whose signature is shown below:

[image]

You need to explicitly pass a crs_wkt value when reading/writing files with geopandas.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Surprisingly enough, I cannot reproduce the issue any longer. When running the code I posted above, I do get the `.prj` file with the info about the `crs`. It could be because I've upgraded `fiona` to `fiona 1.7.0 np110py27_2`.

Comment: Unfortunately there's still the issue in newer versions. I have geopandas 0.4.1 and fiona 1.8.4.