# Buffering line with flat cap style using GeoPandas?

Tags: python, shapefile, buffer, shapely, geopandas

I'm interested in buffering a linestring geometry using a flat cap style rather than the default round cap style using GeoPandas. I see shapely, which geopandas is based off, has the option to do that:

[`object.buffer(distance, resolution=16, cap_style=2, join_style=1, mitre_limit=1.0)`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.buffer)

However, when I try to integrate the cap style into my geopandas script

```py
import geopandas as gp

shp = r'X:\temp\line_shapefile.shp'
outshp =r'X:\temp\buffered_line_shapefile.shp'

df = gp.GeoDataFrame.from_file(shp)
buffer = df.buffer(100, cap_style=2)

buffer.to_file(outshp)
```

it throws an error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-12-9660d1a63146>", line 7, in <module>
    buffer = df.buffer(100, cap_style=2)

TypeError: buffer() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cap_style'
```

What is the correct implimentation of the flat cap style buffer in GeoPandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GeoPandas isn't passing through all arguments to the shapely buffer method. Instead you can use the standard pandas [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) method to call buffer on each geometry individually, e.g.:

```python
# Assumes that geometry will be the geometry column
capped_lines = df.geometry.apply(lambda g: g.buffer(100, cap_style=2))
```

Also, not that this returns a [GeoPandas GeoSeries](http://geopandas.org/data_structures.html#geoseries) object, so if you need the attributes (and projection for that matter, though that [may be an outstanding issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204201/geopandas-to-file-saves-geodataframe-without-coordinate-system)) you'll need to overwite the `geometry` column in the original GeoDataFrame.

Answer (score 3):

GeoPandas now pass `kwargs` to shapely, so you can do below now:

```
gdf.geometry.to_crs("epsg:3857").buffer(10, cap_style=2)
```

PR: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/535

Update: reason for change crs to 3857 is control on buffer radius in meter, else geopandas raise below warning:

`UserWarning: Geometry is in a geographic CRS. Results from 'buffer' are likely incorrect. Use 'GeoSeries.to_crs()' to re-project geometries to a projected CRS before this operation.`