# Renaming columns using geopandas - issues with data table in Arc

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

- Read in an existing ESRI polygon shapefile
- Drop an attribute
- Dissolve by another attribute
- Rename columns
- Reorder columns
- Write out as new shapefile

**What works:** Drop column and dissolve all work - I've run these steps and written to file. This opens fine in ArcMap, I can identify things, open the attribute table etc. No issues.

**Problem:** When I rename (not got to the reorder step without error yet) the columns, everything runs fine and I write to file. When then opening the shapefile in ArcMap (10.3.1) I can query layers using the Identify cursor which shows my renamed attributes as they should be BUT when trying to open the attribute table, I get the following message in a window:

*Loading table data*

*Could not load data from the data source. If you can correct the problem,* *press the refresh button to reload data. Possible problems can include bad* *network connection, invalid file, etc.*

*A column was specified that doesn't exists.*

*A column was specified that doesn't exists.*

So, it looks like something is missing or my changes are not being mapped across the shapefile components.

Given a mock version of the data:

```
# Make a mock geopandas dataframe
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
from fiona.crs import from_epsg

data = gpd.GeoDataFrame()

# Coordinates of some locations in British National Grid (epsg: 27700)
coordinates1 = [(19.950899, 60.169158), (20.953492, 60.169158), (20.950958, 61.169990), (19.953510, 61.170104)]
coordinates2 = [(21.950899, 60.169158), (22.953492, 60.169158), (22.950958, 61.169990), (21.953510, 61.170104)]
coordinates3 = [(19.99, 60.3), (20.23492, 60.3), (20.23492, 60.8), (19.99, 60.8)]

# Create a Shapely polygon from the coordinate-tuple list
poly1 = Polygon(coordinates1)
poly2 = Polygon(coordinates2)
poly3 = Polygon(coordinates3) # (sits inside polygon 1)

# Add polygon to dataframe
data.loc[0, 'geometry'] = poly1
data.loc[1, 'geometry'] = poly2
data.loc[2, 'geometry'] = poly3
data.loc[0, 'value'] = 1
data.loc[1, 'value'] = 2
data.loc[2, 'value'] = 3
data.loc[0, 'CLASS'] = 'A'
data.loc[1, 'CLASS'] = 'B'
data.loc[2, 'CLASS'] = 'A'
data.loc[0, 'Hazard_Pot'] = 'High'
data.loc[1, 'Hazard_Pot'] = 'Low'
data.loc[2, 'Hazard_Pot'] = 'High'
data["contaminat"]="something"

# Define CRS
data.crs = from_epsg(27700)


## Plot it
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#ax1=data.plot()
#data.loc[[2],'geometry'].plot(ax=ax1, color='red') # plot on top of others
#plt.show()
```

We'll now dissolve the polygons based on `Hazard_Pot` and then rename and reorder things. The problem is with the renaming... ***What am I missing?***

```
# Drop a column (if writing out file here, does as expected)
data=data.drop(['CLASS'], axis=1)

# Do the dissolve (if writing out file here, does as expected)
data=data.dissolve(by='Hazard_Pot', as_index=False)

# Rename <<< won't work in ArcGIS 
data=data.rename(index=str, columns={"Hazard_Pot":"Potential",
                        "contaminat":"Contam."}) # <<< EDIT: notice the punctuation (noticed following the accepted answer)

# Reorder 
data=data[['value',
           'Contam.',
           'Potential',
           'geometry']]

# write to file (creating a new CRS based on the old as per https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204201/geopandas-to-file-saves-geodataframe-without-coordinate-system?noredirect=1&lq=1)
ofile='./rename_shape.shp'
data.to_file(ofile, driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

Comment: `data.rename(index=str...` renaming the index to a data type is very strange. Take that part out and report back

Comment: `I can't share the data but can share the code` and you can share fake data that reproduces the issue

Comment: @PaulH i belive `index=str` is correct syntax, see the examples in [help section of rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html). But I also think that part is not needed.

Comment: @BERA Oops - forgot rename could take callables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your code I can see two things that Arcmap doesn't like:

- The first one is the space in the field name  `"building d"`;
- The second one - and the cause of the error - is the `.` in `"contaminat":"Contam."`.

I was able to reproduce the error by creating a test file and using your code. Removing the dot `"contaminat":"Contam"` solved the problem.